# saving string and num together in a matrix, matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to save a string with its corresponding index in a matrix but I am getting an error.

Here is a small example:

```
Mat_=[];            
Val1=[10,19,22,15,30];
Val2=20
Strs_=[];
for i= 1:length(Val1)
if abs(Val1(1,i))<abs(Val2)
            Str_={'Überschritten'};  
        else
            Str_={'Unterschritten'};
end
Strs_=[Strs_;Str_];
Mat_=[Mat_;i];
end
Mat_
Strs_
FMat=[Mat_,Strs_]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a cell array to work with strings. To do this, you can preallocate a cell array and fill it.

```
Val1 = [10,19,22,15,30];
Val2 = 20;
FMat = cell(length(Val1), 2); % Preallocate empty cell array
for idx = 1:length(Val1)
    if abs(Val1(1,idx)) < abs(Val2)
        Str_ = 'Überschritten';  
    else
        Str_ = 'Unterschritten';
    end    
FMat(idx, :) = {idx, Str_};
end
```

Your `FMat` cell array will be:

```
1   'Überschritten'
2   'Überschritten'
3   'Unterschritten'
4   'Überschritten'
5   'Unterschritten'
```

---

Notice that I also changed your loop variable `i` to `idx`. In MATLAB, `i` and `j` are defined as `sqrt(-1)`. It is always a good idea to give your variables other names.

Comment: Two comments: 1. No need for curly braces when assigning to `Str_`. When assigning into `Fmat`, you can also do: `FMat(idx, :) = [idx, Str_];` in one line :)

Comment: Thanks @EitanT. I updated my answer. I like cell arrays with curly braces better, find them much less confusing, so I did a little modification to your suggestion.